# Table Data Resize Web Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, image-resizing, tablelayout

I have a table in a website I'm building that has two rows, each with three data elements nested inside. On large screens it looks just fine, but I would like to stack the table data when a certain threshold is reached. Is this possible with something like a web query and some CSS?

My code is like this example:

```
                    <table id="example">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="" class="FPO"><br />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="" class="FPO"><br />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="" class="FPO"><br />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text">
                                "blah blah balh<br />
                                do re mi fa so la ti<br />
                                the butler did it!"<br />
                                <span class="bold">- me</span>
                             </td>
                            <td class="text">
                                // repeat data
                            </td>
                            <td class="text">
                               // repeat data
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [This](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow) it's a css elliplse property when screen size get smaller than last characted of text will be converted in dots(...), No need to add jquery it will directly done with css.

```css
#div1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>The following two divs contains a long text that will not fit in the box. As you can see, the text is clipped.</p>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope This might help You.